# How to "flatten" a data

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

I have a REST endpoint which takes a POJO and saves it.

```
@Service
public class CassandraService {

    @Autowired MyReactiveCassandraRepository cassandraRepository;

    public Mono<String> save(Pojo pojo) {
        return cassandraRepository.save(pojo);
    }
    
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface MyReactiveCassandraRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Pojo, String> {
```

```
@Table
public class Pojo {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    private String foo;

    private InnerPojo innerPojo;
```

```
public class InnerPojo {

    String aaa;

    String bbb;
```

If you look at the data, you can see there are primitive types, but there is also an Object (InnerPojo in my example).

Instead of storing the data with "two levels", I would like to "flatten" the data, and save it that way:

```
| id | foo | aaa | bbb | 
|----|-----|-----|-----|
|    |     |     |     | 
|    |     |     |     | 
|    |     |     |     |
```

Currently, I am duplicating a POJO entirely:

```
@Table
public class FlattenPojo {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    private String foo;
    
    private String aaa;
    
    private String bbb;
```

And modify, create conversion code in my entire project to save this "duplicate" pojo in order to save the "flatten" version.

Is there a smarter way to save this the flatten formed in Spring Boot?

Comment: Simply don't use ORM, and you wouldn't have this problem

Comment: Did you try a 1:1 relationship?
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "innerPojo_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private InnerPojo innerPojo;

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your `innerPojo` property as `@Transient` and have "flattened" private properties populated by `InnerPojo`when calling the constructor. You have to re-create `InnerPojo` in `@PostConstruct` from those "flattened" properties then when loading.